# Reload SharedPreferences when change made externally (without killing app)

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I`m making backup of Shared_prefs and it restores successfully, but values are not updated on re-loading activity (finish(); statActivity(...);). 
It needs to be killed and then it will load values....
Here is my code:

```
    public pFunctions (Context context ) {
        this.context = context;
        initPrefs();
    }

    private void initPrefs() {
        settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        settings_edit = settings.edit();
        S_UNLOCK_FINGER = settings.getBoolean("finger_unlock", false);
        S_BACKUP_SAVE = settings.getBoolean("backup_saves", true);
        ......
    }
```

every time, on creating or on refreshing activity, i`m calling this functions as

```
prefs = new pFunctions(this);
```

but values stay same until app`s killed as said above. 
My question is: how it is possible to re-load preferences once xml resource file (in data/data/.../shared_prefs) is changed or deleted then added manually?

Comment: "Modifications to the preferences must go through an SharedPreferences.Editor object to ensure the preference values remain in a consistent state and control when they are committed to storage" (from [the JavaDocs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)). AFAIK, there is no way to do what you are seeking.

Comment: But it is loaded once app is killed -> started again.
I mean: 
1. i open app
2. connect to drive and restoring backup...
it replaces xml resource but effect is not applied to activity even when calling defaultSharedPrefs again. It requires app to restart and then xml resource i downloaded earlier, is successfully applied to app... so what role does Editor play here?

Comment: "so what role does Editor play here?" -- `SharedPreferences` *only* supports changing values via the `Editor`. You are changing values by another means. `SharedPreferences` does not support that.

Comment: so, i have no other choice then database to store values

Answer (score 1):

As per the Android documentation you need to use `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` mode to notify the disk changes to shared preference, anyhow this method is now deprecated but this is one of the possible ways to achieve this process.

```
public static boolean reloadSharedPreference(Context context, String name) {
    return context.getSharedPreferences(name, Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS)
            .edit()
            .putBoolean("RELOAD", true)
            .commit();
}
```

Refer the Android docs:

```
/**
 * SharedPreference loading flag: when set, the file on disk will
 * be checked for modification even if the shared preferences
 * instance is already loaded in this process.  This behavior is
 * sometimes desired in cases where the application has multiple
 * processes, all writing to the same SharedPreferences file.
 * Generally there are better forms of communication between
 * processes, though.
 *
 * <p>This was the legacy (but undocumented) behavior in and
 * before Gingerbread (Android 2.3) and this flag is implied when
 * targeting such releases.  For applications targeting SDK
 * versions <em>greater than</em> Android 2.3, this flag must be
 * explicitly set if desired.
 *
 * @see #getSharedPreferences
 *
 * @deprecated MODE_MULTI_PROCESS does not work reliably in
 * some versions of Android, and furthermore does not provide any
 * mechanism for reconciling concurrent modifications across
 * processes.  Applications should not attempt to use it.  Instead,
 * they should use an explicit cross-process data management
 * approach such as {@link android.content.ContentProvider ContentProvider}.
 */
@Deprecated
public static final int MODE_MULTI_PROCESS = 0x0004;
```

Comment: Nice trick to reload from disk if you are touching the files directly.

Comment: Finally, someone really recognized, Thanks.